# Get icons from browser resources

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

Is there possibility to get dynamically images/icons from browser?

I have problem with custom dropdown control (written in ASP/C#). I would like it to have same icon as browser has for standard `select` control. That control has few HTML elements, including `img`, which holds image for dropdown button.

There is no option to use `select` control for this.

There are some differences between browsers and I want it to be cross-browser.

Comment: 99.99% sure the answer to this is "no." 100% certain the answer is "Not reliably cross-browser, no."

Comment: bootstrap use `ul` and `li` tags which replaces the standard browser dropdown, So with this you can have uniform dropdown in all the browsers. This requires jquery and css

Comment: Then, is there possibility to access images even if I write in js code that distinguish between browsers and access resources depending on a browser?. For example for IE its ./res/img/arrDown.ico/png and for Chrome is ./global/dropdown/bttn.png?